# TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

```
   below is my code controller in angular js and html when run this am getting gridDim undefined error please help in resolving the issue---------------
----------------------------------------------------


<div ng-contoller="WritebackgridCtrl">  
        <div class="writebackgridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

js code using controller and in anguar js ..............................................
..........................................................................

```
 angular.module('testApp', ['ngGrid'])
      .controller('WritebackgridCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$rootscope) {
            $scope.myData = []; 

    $scope.myData = [{ column1:'1-07-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww2', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue1', column7:'399', column8:"10", column9:"20", column10:"20", column11:'12'},
                        { column1: '1-08-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue2', column7:'299', column8:"20", column9:"32", column10:"32", column11:'12'},
                        { column1: '1-09-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'499', column8:"30", column9:"34", column10:"34", column11:'13'},
                        { column1: '1-10-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"40", column9:"45", column10:"45", column11:'14'},
                        { column1: '1-11-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue4', column7:'399', column8:"50", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'17'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue5', column7:'399', column8:"60", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'18'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue6', column7:'399', column8:"70", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'20'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"80", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'30'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'89'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'67'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'78'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"16", column10:"16", column11:'65'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"69", column10:"69", column11:'66'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue3', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"69", column10:"69", column11:'45'},
                        { column1: '1-12-2013', column2: 2013, column3: 'ww3', column4: 'oregon', column5:'325152', column6:'testvalue1', column7:'399', column8:"90", column9:"90", column10:"90", clumn11:'56'}];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
            showColumnMenu:true,
           enablePinning: true,
           enableColumnReordering:true,
           enableCellSelection: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
            columnDefs: [{ field: "column1", width: 120,pinned: true },
                        { field: "column2", width: 120,pinned:true},
                        { field: "column3", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column4", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column5", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column6", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column7", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column8", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column9", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false },
                        { field: "column10", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false},
                        { field: "column11", width: 120,pinned:true,headerCellTemplate: 'views/celltemplate.html',enableCellEdit:false }]
        };

      });
```

above is the datawant to render it in grid

Comment: Could you please format your code properly or provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Is the last entry in your json really clumn11 or is that a typo? Can't check if this causes the error because angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ is down at this moment.

Comment: it is column11 eventhough i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

There are several typos in you example that might be responsible for your error.

In the html part it should be:

```
<div ng-controller="WritebackGridCtrl">  
        <div class="WritebackGridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

instead of `ng-contoller`

If you want inject the rootscope in the controller it should be:

```
app.controller('WritebackGridCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope)
```

instead of `$rootscope` (note the camelcase).

I already mentioned the typo in your json but this shouldn't produce an error.

Also you should keep your notation more consistent and use `WritebackGridCtrl` and `WritebackGridStyle`.

See everything working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbmAjV?p=preview)